# Delete WordPress plugin completely

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress e-commerce website and i want to add wallet system in it i installed **TeraWallet for woocommerce** plugin wallet is working fine but on my account page my wallet page is not showing there is some error. Give me any solution how to solve this i tried to uninstall the plugin and reinstall it but it doesn't work because plugin reinstalls with the old data how to uninstall plugin completely and reinstall with new settings I'm stuch here how to solve this issue